# Odd result by using DirectorySearcher

Tags: active-directory

I am using `DirectorySearcher` to get all AD users' display name from company AD server, we have around 100k records and most of results are correct.

But we got near 100 users' display name are "$CimsUserVersion2", it's really a odd result, I checked in outlook which also sync display name from AD, the name is correct

Have u facing same issue?

Thanks a lot

```
using (var de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domain))
{
   using (var search = new DirectorySearcher(de))
   {
       search.Filter = "CN=" + userName;
       var results = search.FindAll();
       string temp = results[0].Properties["displayname"][0].ToString();

       if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(temp))
       {
          return string.Empty;
       }
       else
       {
          return temp;
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's the problem - but I think you'd need to tell your searcher that you want the `displayName` attribute to be loaded:

```
using (var de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domain))
{
   using (var search = new DirectorySearcher(de))
   {
       search.Filter = "CN=" + userName;
       search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayName");  // specify "displayname" to be returned from search

       var results = search.FindAll();

       string temp = results[0].Properties["displayname"][0].ToString();

       if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(temp))
       {
          return string.Empty;
       }
       else
       {
          return temp;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, 100k users got their correct DisplayName, only a few are strange value -looks it's not a code level problem

Answer (score 0):

Don't you automate the provisioning of UNIX users and groups into Microsoft Active Directory  with "**[Centrify DirectControl](http://www.centrify.com/directcontrol/overview.asp)**".

This tool uses a simple object model to manage the UNIX-specific properties for users, groups, computers, and zones, as well as UNIX NIS services.

As far as I understand it uses Active-Directory attributes to register some special informations.

UserVersion is map to `displayName` :

UserVersion determines compatibility between a user profile object and the Centrify DirectControl Administrator Console. The only valid value for this attribute is **$CimsUserVersion2**.

For example:

displayName: $CimsUserVersion2

Comment: Thanks - displayName is a attribute i want to get from AD, in our outlook, we can see this odd user have correct display name, for example, Gary Wang, but when i use .net method, it returns  $CimsUserVersion2, the odd thing is most of users it's OK, just for those 100 users, is it any issue for our AD or .net issue?

Comment: Please Gary, have a look in your AD with LDP.EXE, or ADSIEDIT.MSC and verify `displayName` attribute for one of the 100 users. I'am quite sure that the attribute really contains the value `$CimsUserVersion2`.